# Optimizing for-enumerate loop with numba - optimized version is slower

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to optimize this function with numba:

```
@jit(nopython=False, forceobj=True)
def _packing_loop(data: List[str], indices: np.ndarray, strings: List[str], offsets: List[int], str_map: Dict[str, int], acc_len):
    for i, s in enumerate(data):
        # handle null strings.
        if not s:
            indices[i] = -1
            continue

        index = str_map.get(s)
        if index is None:
            # increment the length
            acc_len += len(s)

            # store the string and index
            index = len(strings)
            strings.append(s)
            # strings += s,
            str_map[s] = index

            # write the offset
            offsets.append(acc_len)
            # offsets += acc_len,

        indices[i] = index
```

The issue is that the optimized code is ~1.5 times slower (even if I pre-run the function once before benchmarking).

What is the possible reason?
I would be also grateful for any suggestions on how to actually optimize this function.

P.S. I am not limited to numba, other approaches are also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forceobj` generate an inefficient code. To quote the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html?highlight=forceobj):

> If true, **forceobj** forces the function to be compiled in **object mode**. Since **object mode is slower than nopython mode**, this is mostly useful for testing purposes.

You should not use it in production. Besides, Numba do not supports well reflected lists. You should **use typed lists** for sake of performance. In fact, typing is what makes Numba fast. Without types, Numba cannot generate a compiled code and a slow interpreted version is executed. Note that strings are barely supported and clearly not efficient yet. AFAIK, Numba does not benefit from mypy type annocation like `List[str]`. I advise you to use Cython in this case. That being said, the speed up will be certainly small since you are dealing mostly with slow CPython dynamic objects.